# Split large dataset for predictive modeling using rsparkling -sparklyr

Tags: predictive-modeling, bigdata, rstudio, machine-learning-model

I am trying to build machine learning models (GBM, RF, Staking)
on top of a dataset that is about 3G in size on my local computer.
However, I only have 4G memory (only 2G are available).

My question is : is it logical to split the whole data on 20% for 
training set, 10% on validation set, and the 70% for the testing part?
I split also the test set on 7 equal subsets with same distributions.
I am doing this due to the fact I cannot test a model on full dataset.

Still I am not really convinced about this solution, and I am not sure
that it is good enough to get a robust final model. 
 What can I do? I am new to machine learning and big data.

Comment: what are the largest data sizes you have tested with your current lap-top? I think you can do some stuff with the configs you have but you need to make sure you don't exceed certain limits. Have you tried spark?